# Take data from 2 tables at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

For a project, I need to pull data from 2 different tables at the same time. But I just couldn't do it.

For example, there are 2 tables.

Table 1 and Table 2

I want to get the data in Table 1 and Table 2 with status = 1 in the same array.

How can I do that?

I've tried things like Left Join, Right Join, Inner Join. But it never happened. Therefore, it would be nice if there is a way to get them with a single query without using join.

```
table 1 : people
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   id  |   name    |   status  |       phone       |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   1   |   John    |       1   |   214-444-1234    |
|   2   |   Mary    |       0   |   555-111-1234    |
|   3   |   Jeff    |       0   |   214-222-1234    |
|   4   |   Bill    |       1   |   817-333-1234    |
|   5   |   Bob     |       1   |   214-555-1234    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

```
table 2 : dog
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   id  |   name    |   status  |       ids         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   1   |   Holly   |       1   |   223-444-1234    |
|   2   |   Papa    |       0   |   245-111-1234    |
|   3   |   Kozz    |       0   |   234-222-1234    |
|   4   |   Japs    |       1   |   856-333-1234    |
|   5   |   Moly    |       1   |   256-555-1234    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

I want to get, status = 1 peoples and dogs in single array.

Plural code

```
1- SELECT * FROM people WHERE people.status = 1
2- SELECT * FROM dog WHERE dog.status = 1
```

I want this result:

```
$all_data = array(
            '0' => array(
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'John',
                'status' => 1,
                'phone' => '214-444-1234',
                ),
            '2' => array(
                'id' => 4,
                'name' => 'Bill',
                'status' => 1,
                'phone' => '817-333-1234',
            ),
            '3' => array(
                'id' => 5,
                'name' => 'Bob',
                'status' => 1,
                'phone' => '214-555-1234',
            ),
            '4' => array(
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Holly',
                'status' => 1,
                'ids' => '223-444-1234',
            ),
            '5' => array(
                'id' => 4,
                'name' => 'Japs',
                'status' => 1,
                'ids' => '856-333-1234',
            ),
            '6' => array(
                'id' => 5,
                'name' => 'Moly',
                'status' => 1,
                'ids' => '256-555-1234',
            ),
            );
```

How can I do this?

Comment: We can't help you unless you give us more information. Please read this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: Hi, Show us the real Schema for these 2 tables. If possible also show us some example date In fact [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) **It would be useful to also see the queries you have tried**

Comment: ' without using join.'  - Perhaps UNION but really cannot say without sample data

Comment: To get data from two table we need a foreign key in the second table in your case "language_id". User query something like this : Select t0.id, t0.name,t1.namet1 from t0 left join t0.id = t1. language_id where t0.id = 1

Comment: @Ravi Kumar you don't need a foreign key (or any sort of key) to join tables. You only need columns which have a meaningful relationship

Comment: @O.Jones 

I'm edited the my question. Can you check again?

Comment: @RiggsFolly 

I'm edited the my question. Can you check again?

Comment: @P.Salmon 

I'm edited the my question. Can you check again?

Comment: @RaviKumar  I'm edited the my question. Can you check again?

Comment: _“I want to get the data in Table 1 and Table 2 with language_id = 1 in the same array.”_ - what `language_id`? Neither of the two tables you have currently shown does contain a column by that name.

Comment: @04FS status=1, sorry for that, check again please

Comment: Well then a simple UNION of the two queries you have should totally suffice.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. as the status field is not a foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, name, status, phone from people where status = 1
UNION ALL
select id, name, status, phone from dog where status = 1
```